# How do i make a Histogram spanning multiple files?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

i want to make a histogram spanning multiple files in a Folder. 
Example:

File 1:

```
Alpha
Beta 
Ceta  
Delta
```

File 2:

```
Delta 
Ceta 
Alpha
```

File 3:

```
Beta 
Delta
```

I know that i can create a histogram using Numpy with: 
`axHistx = plt.axes(range)`

How can i use this to create a histogram over multiple files, that gives me the absolute number of Occurrences of the Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to count the numbers of instances across all files, you could do this:

```
counts = {}
for f in filenames:
    for val in [s.strip() for s in open(f).readlines()]:
        counts[val] = counts.get(val, 0) + 1
```